# Horizontal scrollbar with centered pictures of unknown height

Tags: html, css

I want to make in html/css (without js) a block with pictures taken from the data base with horizontal scrollbar so that they would be centered regardless of their height.

The only solutions I found to center pictures of unknown height were to use `display: table` or `display: flex`. But the only solution to make a horizontal scrollbar I found requires to use `display: block`. Is there any way to achieve both tasks?

EDIT:

Like on this picture. I meant that pics should be centered having different height:

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0mo5.png)

Comment: Why would you see a horizontal scroll bar "regardless of height"? Do you mean a vertical scroll bar regardless of height? Are you saying you want a div with a fixed height, to display pictures centered within it vertically and horizontally but also show the scroll bar with the scroll starting at the center of the image?

Comment: some html  code and a 'picture' of what you're trying to accomplish would help you to get advise & answer

Answer (score 0):

You had to give some of your code and perhaps a better explanation of what you want to achieve. I am not sure if this will work, but... try this in CSS :

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

on your pictures.